# Error in TextView showing in xml layout setContentView(R.layout.main) after update the gradle and android support library version

Tags: android, version-control, android-gradle-plugin

Recently i have update the android gradle and support library version in android. But now for me it showing issue in xml layout setContentView(R.layout.main). It show error like this

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method
>   getFont(Landroid/content/Context;ILandroid/util/TypedValue;ILandroid/widget/TextView;)Landroid/graphics/Typeface;
>   in class Landroid/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat; or its super
>   classes (declaration of
>   'android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat' appears in
>   /data/app/com.test.app-1/base.apk:classes6.dex)

If i removed Textview from the layout its not showing any issues and working fine. But I need Textview how can i solve this issue.

I have set version like this

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 26

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.2'


classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
```

**XML**

```
<TextView 
  style="@style/TextAppearance.TitleTwo" 
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:gravity="center" 
  android:padding="4dp" 
  android:text="@string/go_shopping" 
  android:textColor="@color/black" />
```

Comment: which `textView ` post related xml

Comment: Yes, it's related to xml.

Comment: I have declare TextView in whole project like this

Comment: I have tried but still passing same issue, not solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your build tool version to same as support library version

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 26

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.2'

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
```

I have faced same problem and it worked for me :)

Comment: I have tried but still passing same issue, not solve the issue.

Comment: @BhargavParmar have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47126127/6121643)

Comment: Finally, it's working for me, thanks for referring this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47126127/7467281

Comment: @BhargavParmar happy to help :)