# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getFont

Tags: android, textview, android-support-library, calligraphy

I am using [Calligraphy Library](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) by ChrisJenx. Suddenly today morning my project has started throwing weird error. Anyone got any idea about this? I also tried looking at **TintTypedArray.java:119**. The one in gradle cache has getFont method which is v26.0.2 but in sdk/extras doesn't have which is v25.3.1. I think gradle cache code would be used for this but still it is throwing error. Please help.

**Logcat:**

> 12-06 16:52:40.516 18533-18533/com.nabta E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                  Process: com.nabta, PID: 18533
>                                                                  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method
>   getFont(Landroid/content/Context;ILandroid/util/TypedValue;ILandroid/widget/TextView;)Landroid/graphics/Typeface;
>   in class Landroid/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat; or its super
>   classes (declaration of
>   'android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat' appears in
>   /data/app/com.nabta-2/base.apk:classes13.dex)
>                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getFont(TintTypedArray.java:119)
>                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.updateTypefaceAndStyle(AppCompatTextHelper.java:208)
>                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:110)
>                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelperV17.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelperV17.java:38)
>                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:81)
>                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:71)
>                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
>                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
>                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
>                                                                      at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater$WrapperFactory2.onCreateView(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:280)
>                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
>                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
>                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:865)
>                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
>                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
>                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
>                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:525)
>                                                                      at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60)
>                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
>                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:378)
>                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
>                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
>                                                                      at com.nabta.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
>                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6977)
>                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3064)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1659)
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6816)
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451)

Comment: try to invalidate caches and restart.If problem persist revert to library version you were using earlier and rebuild

Comment: It is the same library version I was using earlier. There has been no change in this.

Comment: @Mushirih nope. Same result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getFont(Landroid/content/Context;ILandroid/util/TypedValue;ILandroid/widget/TextView;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113948/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-static-method-getfontlandroid-content-contexti)

Answer (score 2):

I solved the bug. After running studio 3.0.0 I had encountered this bug. Upgrading build tools version as suggested here solved it : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47126127/3484668

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was using **[Android-KTX](https://github.com/android/android-ktx)**: `implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:0.1'` in **Kotlin** project, and that was the cause of the error. I just removed it from **build.gradle** as a dependency.

P.S same answer from my post: 
[java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getFont(Landroid/content/Context;ILandroid/util/TypedValue;ILandroid/widget/TextView;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113948/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-static-method-getfontlandroid-content-contexti/48885264#48885264)

Answer (score 0):

Updating the build gradle worked for me.

```
compileSdkVersion 27

targetSdkVersion 27

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.0'
}
```