# Project crashes at launch after updating Android Studio.Why is it crashing?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I was making a project and in order to use Glide library, I updated my android studio to 3.0.1 Since then, I am not able to run my app on my device. I have used firebase in my project and the log cat shows errors as given in the code sample.

```
    12-07 21:14:43.286 1821-2167/? E/QCOM PowerHAL: Error opening sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor: No such file or directory
12-07 21:14:43.286 1821-2167/? E/QCOM PowerHAL: Error opening sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor: No such file or directory
12-07 21:14:43.287 1821-2167/? E/QCOM PowerHAL: Error opening sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_governor: No such file or directory
12-07 21:14:43.287 1821-2167/? E/QCOM PowerHAL: Error opening sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_governor: No such file or directory
12-07 21:14:43.287 1821-2167/? E/QCOM PowerHAL: Can't obtain scaling governor.
12-07 21:14:43.292 325-325/? E/qdutils: int qdutils::getHDMINode(): Failed to open fb node 2
12-07 21:14:43.292 325-325/? E/qdutils: int qdutils::getHDMINode(): Failed to open fb node 3
12-07 21:14:43.292 325-325/? E/qdutils: int qdutils::getHDMINode(): Failed to find HDMI node
12-07 21:14:43.341 1821-2433/? E/AlarmManager: RTC Alarm: 2 null com.facebook.katana X.2Nx.ACTION_ALARM.com.facebook.katana.Mqtt_Wakeup

                                               [ 12-07 21:14:43.349  1821: 1821 D/         ]
                                               set_speaker_light_locked mode 0, colorRGB=1D0000FF, onMS=0, offMS=0
12-07 21:14:43.387 325-660/? E/qdutils: int qdutils::getHDMINode(): Failed to open fb node 2
12-07 21:14:43.387 325-660/? E/qdutils: int qdutils::getHDMINode(): Failed to open fb node 3
12-07 21:14:43.387 325-660/? E/qdutils: int qdutils::getHDMINode(): Failed to find HDMI node

                                        [ 12-07 21:14:43.396  1821: 4643 D/         ]
                                        batch called handle:3 sample_ns:20000000 latency_ns:0

                                        [ 12-07 21:14:43.396  1821: 4643 D/         ]
                                        activate called handle:3 enable:1

                                        [ 12-07 21:14:43.396  1821: 4643 D/         ]
                                        PA12200001 Proximity calling driver setDelay 20 ms


                                        [ 12-07 21:14:43.396  1821: 4643 D/         ]
                                        PA12200001 Proximity calling driver enable
12-07 21:14:43.775 338-1759/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19
12-07 21:14:43.775 338-1759/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB AFE returned = -19
12-07 21:14:46.711 1821-4655/? E/AlarmManager: RTC Alarm: 0 null com.UCMobile.intl com.taobao.accs.intent.action.COMMAND
12-07 21:14:47.647 1821-4655/? E/AlarmManager: RTC Alarm: 0 null com.UCMobile.intl com.taobao.accs.intent.action.COMMAND
12-07 21:14:49.441 1731-1731/com.example.sambal.firebaseregisterauthentication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                 Process: com.example.sambal.firebaseregisterauthentication, PID: 1731
                                                                                                 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getFont(Landroid/content/Context;ILandroid/util/TypedValue;ILandroid/widget/TextView;)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; in class Landroid/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat' appears in /data/app/com.example.sambal.firebaseregisterauthentication-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getFont(TintTypedArray.java:119)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.updateTypefaceAndStyle(AppCompatTextHelper.java:208)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:110)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelperV17.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelperV17.java:38)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:81)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:71)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:67)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.setTitle(Toolbar.java:753)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.setTitleInt(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:261)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.setWindowTitle(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:243)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setWindowTitle(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:621)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onTitleChanged(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:631)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:328)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                                                     at com.example.sambal.firebaseregisterauthentication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
                                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6684)
                                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2652)
                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2766)
                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1507)
                                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6236)
                                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891)
                                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)
12-07 21:14:49.519 12379-12379/? E/AppCrashReceiver: com.example.sambal.firebaseregisterauthentication stopped unexpectedly...
12-07 21:14:51.776 1821-4640/? E/ActivityManager: applyOptionsLocked: Unknown animationType=0
12-07 21:14:53.269 1987-1987/com.example.sambal.firebaseregisterauthentication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                 Process: com.example.sambal.firebaseregisterauthentication, PID: 1987
                                                                                                 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getFont(Landroid/content/Context;ILandroid/util/TypedValue;ILandroid/widget/TextView;)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; in class Landroid/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat' appears in /data/app/com.example.sambal.firebaseregisterauthentication-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getFont(TintTypedArray.java:119)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.updateTypefaceAndStyle(AppCompatTextHelper.java:208)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:110)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelperV17.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelperV17.java:38)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:81)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:71)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:67)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.setTitle(Toolbar.java:753)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.setTitleInt(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:261)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.setWindowTitle(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:243)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setWindowTitle(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:621)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onTitleChanged(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:631)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:328)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                                                     at com.example.sambal.firebaseregisterauthentication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
                                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6684)
                                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2652)
                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2766)
                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1507)
                                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6236)
                                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891)
                                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)
12-07 21:14:53.285 12379-12379/? E/AppCrashReceiver: 'com.example.sambal.firebaseregisterauthentication' is repeatedly stopping...
12-07 21:14:53.285 12379-12379/? E/AppCrashReceiver: Now disabling all overlays for 'com.example.sambal.firebaseregisterauthentication'...
12-07 21:15:02.003 1821-4642/? E/AlarmManager: RTC Alarm: 2 null com.facebook.katana KeepaliveManager.ACTION_INEXACT_ALARM.FBNS.com.facebook.katana
12-07 21:15:02.004 1821-11080/? E/AlarmManager: RTC Alarm: 2 null com.facebook.katana KeepaliveManager.ACTION_BACKUP_ALARM.FBNS.com.facebook.katana
12-07 21:15:02.018 1821-4634/? E/AlarmManager: RTC Alarm: 2 null com.facebook.katana X.07w.ACTION_ALARM.FBNS.com.facebook.katana
12-07 21:15:55.132 1821-9208/? E/AlarmManager: RTC Alarm: 2 null com.android.systemui com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.DELAYED_KEYGUARD
12-07 21:15:55.592 325-325/? E/qdutils: int qdutils::getHDMINode(): Failed to open fb node 2
12-07 21:15:55.593 325-325/? E/qdutils: int qdutils::getHDMINode(): Failed to open fb node 3
12-07 21:15:55.593 325-325/? E/qdutils: int qdutils::getHDMINode(): Failed to find HDMI node
12-07 21:15:55.898 325-660/? E/qdutils: int qdutils::getHDMINode(): Failed to open fb node 2
12-07 21:15:55.898 325-660/? E/qdutils: int qdutils::getHDMINode(): Failed to open fb node 3
12-07 21:15:55.898 325-660/? E/qdutils: int qdutils::getHDMINode(): Failed to find HDMI node
12-07 21:15:55.966 1821-2167/? E/QCOM PowerHAL: Error opening sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor: No such file or directory
12-07 21:15:55.966 1821-2167/? E/QCOM PowerHAL: Error opening sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor: No such file or directory
12-07 21:15:55.966 1821-2167/? E/QCOM PowerHAL: Error opening sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_governor: No such file or directory
12-07 21:15:55.966 1821-2167/? E/QCOM PowerHAL: Error opening sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_governor: No such file or directory
12-07 21:15:55.966 1821-2167/? E/QCOM PowerHAL: Can't obtain scaling governor.
12-07 21:15:56.002 1821-30172/? E/AlarmManager: RTC Alarm: 2 null com.facebook.orca X.1Io.ACTION_ALARM.com.facebook.orca.Mqtt_Wakeup
12-07 21:15:56.015 1821-2433/? E/AlarmManager: RTC Alarm: 2 null com.facebook.katana X.2Nx.ACTION_ALARM.com.facebook.katana.Mqtt_Wakeup

                                               [ 12-07 21:15:56.022  1821: 1821 D/         ]
                                               set_speaker_light_locked mode 1, colorRGB=FFFF0000, onMS=500, offMS=2000
12-07 21:15:56.092 1821-1821/? E/AlarmManager: RTC Alarm: 2 null android com.android.server.ACTION_TRIGGER_IDLE
12-07 21:15:56.692 1821-4655/? E/AlarmManager: RTC Alarm: 0 null com.google.android.gms null.INACTIVITY_TRIGGERED
12-07 21:16:42.356 1821-2431/? E/AlarmManager: RTC Alarm: 2 null com.instagram.android com.facebook.rti.mqtt.f.e.ACTION_BACKUP_ALARM.FBNS.com.instagram.android
12-07 21:16:42.387 1821-3656/? E/AlarmManager: RTC Alarm: 2 null com.instagram.android com.facebook.rti.mqtt.common.e.x.ACTION_ALARM.FBNS.com.instagram.android
12-07 21:16:53.832 1821-1837/? E/BatteryStatsService: power: Missing API
12-07 21:16:53.834 1821-1834/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
12-07 21:16:53.843 1821-1837/? E/BatteryStatsService: no controller energy info supplied
12-07 21:16:53.843 1821-1837/? E/BatteryStatsService: no controller energy info supplied
12-07 21:16:53.861 1821-1837/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
12-07 21:16:53.874 1821-1837/? E/BatteryStatsService: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
12-07 21:17:28.567 1821-9208/? E/AlarmManager: RTC Alarm: 2 null com.google.android.gms com.google.android.gms.gcm.HEARTBEAT_ALARM
12-07 21:17:28.652 1821-11080/? E/AlarmManager: RTC Alarm: 2 null com.google.android.gms com.google.android.gms.gcm.ACTION_CHECK_QUEUE
12-07 21:17:28.759 1821-11080/? E/AlarmManager: RTC Alarm: 2 null com.google.android.gms com.google.android.gms.gcm.HEARTBEAT_ALARM
12-07 21:17:28.787 1821-9205/? E/AlarmManager: RTC Alarm: 2 null com.google.android.gms com.google.android.gms.gcm.ACTION_CHECK_QUEUE
12-07 21:17:56.076 1821-2431/? E/AlarmManager: RTC Alarm: 2 null com.facebook.katana X.2Nx.ACTION_ALARM.com.facebook.katana.Mqtt_Wakeup
12-07 21:18:16.876 1821-9205/? E/AlarmManager: RTC Alarm: 2 null com.google.android.gms com.google.android.gms.gcm.HEARTBEAT_ALARM
12-07 21:18:17.003 1821-2204/? E/AlarmManager: RTC Alarm: 2 null com.google.android.gms com.google.android.gms.gcm.ACTION_CHECK_QUEUE
12-07 21:18:17.031 1135-2289/? E/TESTING**: shouldRunSapiForUiForAccount: false
12-07 21:18:17.047 1135-2289/? E/TESTING**: shouldRunSapiForUiForAccount: false
12-07 21:18:17.047 1135-2289/? E/TESTING**: shouldRunSapiForUiForAccount: false
12-07 21:18:17.047 1135-2289/? E/TESTING**: shouldRunSapiForUiForAccount: false
12-07 21:18:17.048 1135-2289/? E/TESTING**: shouldRunSapiForUiForAccount: false
12-07 21:18:17.049 1135-2289/? E/TESTING**: shouldRunSapiForUiForAccount: false
12-07 21:18:17.054 1135-2289/? E/TESTING**: shouldRunSapiForUiForAccount: false
12-07 21:18:17.054 1135-2289/? E/TESTING**: shouldRunSapiForUiForAccount: false
12-07 21:18:17.054 1135-2289/? E/TESTING**: shouldRunSapiForUiForAccount: false
12-07 21:18:17.055 1135-2289/? E/TESTING**: shouldRunSapiForUiForAccount: false
12-07 21:18:17.068 1821-3545/? E/AlarmManager: RTC Alarm: 2 null com.google.android.gms com.google.android.gms.gcm.ACTION_CHECK_QUEUE
12-07 21:18:17.371 1821-2435/? E/AlarmManager: RTC Alarm: 0 null com.UCMobile.intl com.taobao.accs.intent.action.COMMAND
12-07 21:18:20.501 1821-3545/? E/AlarmManager: RTC Alarm: 2 null com.google.android.gms com.google.android.gms.gcm.ACTION_CHECK_QUEUE
12-07 21:18:20.890 1135-2297/? E/TESTING**: shouldRunSapiForUiForAccount: false
12-07 21:18:20.897 1135-2297/? E/TESTING**: shouldRunSapiForUiForAccount: false
12-07 21:18:20.897 1135-2297/? E/TESTING**: shouldRunSapiForUiForAccount: false
12-07 21:18:20.898 1135-2297/? E/TESTING**: shouldRunSapiForUiForAccount: false
12-07 21:18:20.898 1135-2297/? E/TESTING**: shouldRunSapiForUiForAccount: false
12-07 21:18:20.899 1135-2297/? E/TESTING**: shouldRunSapiForUiForAccount: false
12-07 21:18:20.912 1135-2297/? E/TESTING**: shouldRunSapiForUiForAccount: false
12-07 21:18:20.913 1135-2297/? E/TESTING**: shouldRunSapiForUiForAccount: false
12-07 21:18:20.927 1135-2298/? E/TESTING**: shouldRunSapiForUiForAccount: false
12-07 21:18:20.936 1135-2298/? E/TESTING**: shouldRunSapiForUiForAccount: false
12-07 21:18:20.936 1135-2298/? E/TESTING**: shouldRunSapiForUiForAccount: false
12-07 21:18:20.936 1135-2298/? E/TESTING**: shouldRunSapiForUiForAccount: false
12-07 21:18:20.937 1135-2298/? E/TESTING**: shouldRunSapiForUiForAccount: false
12-07 21:18:20.938 1135-2298/? E/TESTING**: shouldRunSapiForUiForAccount: false
12-07 21:18:20.951 1135-2298/? E/TESTING**: shouldRunSapiForUiForAccount: false
12-07 21:18:20.951 1135-2298/? E/TESTING**: shouldRunSapiForUiForAccount: false
12-07 21:18:20.952 1135-2298/? E/TESTING**: shouldRunSapiForUiForAccount: false
12-07 21:18:20.953 1135-2298/? E/TESTING**: shouldRunSapiForUiForAccount: false
12-07 21:18:27.222 1821-1832/? E/AlarmManager: RTC Alarm: 0 null com.jiochat.jiochatapp com.jiochat.jiochatapp.FIN_ALARM
12-07 21:18:56.285 1821-1837/? E/BatteryStatsService: power: Missing API
12-07 21:18:56.287 1821-1834/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
12-07 21:18:56.297 1821-1837/? E/BatteryStatsService: no controller energy info supplied
12-07 21:18:56.297 1821-1837/? E/BatteryStatsService: no controller energy info supplied
12-07 21:18:56.309 1821-1837/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
12-07 21:18:56.322 1821-1837/? E/BatteryStatsService: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
12-07 21:20:52.178 1821-2142/? E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ LISTEN id=114, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&FOREGROUND] ]
12-07 21:20:52.179 1821-2142/? E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ LISTEN id=116, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&FOREGROUND] ]
12-07 21:20:52.181 1821-2142/? E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ LISTEN id=112, [ Capabilities: NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN&FOREGROUND] ]
12-07 21:21:48.597 1821-1837/? E/BatteryStatsService: power: Missing API
```

The screesshot of the logcat is:
[Logcat Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LP5Xk.png)

I updeted my firebase dependency,ANdroid studio and since then I am experiencing these problems. Can someone tell what are the possible problems?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113948/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-static-method-getfontlandroid-content-contexti

Comment: @Wilik thanks. It helped me a lot and it worked for me.