# notifydatasetchanged() method not working RecyclerView on Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit2, android-adapter

My Application crashed on **Android 6**,
I'm using Retrofit with custom adapter `RecyclerView` 
when I call `notifydatasetchanged()`: Method not working `RecyclerView`

This is My Adapter Class

**AnswersAdapter.java**

```
public class AnswersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AnswersAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Item> mItems;
    private Context mContext;
    private PostItemListener mItemListener;


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        public TextView titleTv;
        PostItemListener mItemListener;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView, PostItemListener postItemListener) {
            super(itemView);
            titleTv =  itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

            this.mItemListener = postItemListener;
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Item item = getItem(getAdapterPosition());
            this.mItemListener.onPostClick(item.getAnswerId());

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public AnswersAdapter(Context context, List<Item> posts, PostItemListener itemListener) {
        mItems = posts;
        mContext = context;
        mItemListener = itemListener;
    }

    @Override
    public AnswersAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        View postView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(postView, this.mItemListener);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AnswersAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Item item = mItems.get(position);
        TextView textView = holder.titleTv;
        textView.setText(item.getOwner().getDisplayName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    public void updateAnswers(List<Item> items) {
        mItems.clear();
        mItems.addAll(items);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private Item getItem(int adapterPosition) {
        return mItems.get(adapterPosition);
    }

    public interface PostItemListener {
        void onPostClick(long id);
    }
}
```

This my main Activity
**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AnswersAdapter mAdapter;
    private SOService mService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mService = ApiUtils.getSOService();
        RecyclerView mRecyclerView =  findViewById(R.id.rvawnser);
        mAdapter = new AnswersAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Item>(0),
                new AnswersAdapter.PostItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPostClick(long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Post id is" + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.ItemDecoration itemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
        loadAnswers();

    }

    public void loadAnswers() {
        mService.getAnswers().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<SOAnswersResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(SOAnswersResponse soAnswersResponse) {
                        mAdapter.updateAnswers(soAnswersResponse.getItems());
                    }
                });
    }
    private void showErrorMessage() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MainActivity: error loading from API", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Its working fine when I remove

```
mAdapter.updateAnswers(soAnswersResponse.getItems());
```

And this is error log

> 12-25 07:34:49.535 17676-17676/com.example.masoudmk.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                       Process: com.example.masoudmk.myapplication, PID: 17676
>                                                                                       java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method
>   getFont(Landroid/content/Context;ILandroid/util/TypedValue;ILandroid/widget/TextView;)Landroid/graphics/Typeface;
>   in class Landroid/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat; or its super
>   classes (declaration of
>   'android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat' appears in
>   /data/app/com.example.masoudmk.myapplication-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getFont(TintTypedArray.java:119)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.updateTypefaceAndStyle(AppCompatTextHelper.java:208)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:110)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelperV17.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelperV17.java:38)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:81)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:71)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.example.masoudmk.myapplication.AnswersAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(AnswersAdapter.java:54)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.example.masoudmk.myapplication.AnswersAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(AnswersAdapter.java:13)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6519)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5706)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5589)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5585)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2231)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1558)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1518)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:610)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3719)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3135)
>                                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:934)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:973)
>                                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
>                                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>                                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
>                                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
>                                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
>                                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
>                                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
>                                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
>                                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>                                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>                                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
>                                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
>                                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
>                                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.masoudmk.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2'
        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.2'
               // Retrofit
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
         compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'

        // JSON Parsing
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'

    enter code here
        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'

        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
}
```

what is the Problem?

Comment: can you add your adapter code and the error log?

Comment: it dosnt Have a Error , just Crashed When i open ,
Say my application has Stopped

Comment: Just click on the logcat and you will get the error log

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getFont(Landroid/content/Context;ILandroid/util/TypedValue;ILandroid/widget/TextView;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113948/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-static-method-getfontlandroid-content-contexti)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your gradle this way :

```
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
```

and

```
dependencies {

...

compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.0.0'
...


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is about support libraries version. Check your build tools version and dependencies version at app.gradle file. They must be same.

```
android: {
    ....
    buildToolsVersion: 'VERSION'
    ....
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
    ......
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:VERSION'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:VERSION'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:VERSION'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:VERSION'
    .....
}
```

Comment: Im Check it,its ok and i add code to my question Check it please