# Getting error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getFont... after rewriting XML files

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried to upload my working project on github but failed to upload XML files and lost them somehow because I have never used github before, now when I re write the XML files for my project I'm facing this error from the compiler:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getFont(Landroid/content/Context;ILandroid/util/TypedValue;ILandroid/widget/TextView;)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; in class Landroid/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat' appears in /data/app/com.example.syyam.dietplan-1/base.apk)
```

I have looked for the solution for this and found this solution but it didn't work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47126127/6473155

[Here's the full picture of the error i'm getting:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFsIJ.png)

My app level gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.syyam.dietplan"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Edit: the xml file of my launcher acctivity is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".EEG">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textSize="19dp"
                android:text="Alpha   "
                />
            <SeekBar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="12"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/mSeekAlpha"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/alphaCount"
                android:text="0.0"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"

                />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:text="Beta     "/>
            <SeekBar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="12"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/mSeekBeta"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/betaCount"
                android:text="0.0"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"

                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:text="Delta    "/>
            <SeekBar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="12"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/mSeekDelta"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/deltaCount"
                android:text="0.0"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"

                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:text="Theta   "/>
            <SeekBar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="12"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/mSeekTheta"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/thetaCount"
                android:text="0.0"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"

                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textSize="19dp"
                android:text="Gamma"/>
            <SeekBar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="12"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/mSeekGamma"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/gammaCount"
                android:text="0.0"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"

                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/subBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and the manifest looks like that:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.syyam.dietplan">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".EEG">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Suffering" />
        <activity android:name=".DisorederWebView" />
        <activity android:name=".ChoosePlan" />
        <activity android:name=".Schedule" />
        <activity android:name=".DailyAppContent" />
        <activity android:name=".WeeklyAppContent" />
        <activity android:name=".MonthlyAppContent" />
        <activity android:name=".OverallSchedule" />
        <activity android:name=".WeeklyDailyAppContent" />
        <activity android:name=".MonthlyDailyAppContent" />
        <activity android:name=".chooseTestType" />
        <activity android:name=".history" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My new XML files didn't get upload on the github because I remained them unchecked while committing and [their java files also got corrupted like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUqVV.png) So I corrected them manually by removing the <<<<<

Comment: So you lost everything in the res folder? What about your manifest file?

Comment: Can you post the xml file that causes this error?

Comment: No i didn't lost everything, I already have uploaded my whole project (previous version) on the github, those files are safe. After the recent upload I lost only the new XML files i made and my new java files also got corrupted.

Comment: @Sub6Resources I have uploaded the launcher XML files. Kindly check that.

Comment: Maybe try a clean build. It's under `Build` -> `Clean Project` in Android Studio.

Comment: @Sub6Resources have done that a million time, tried doing invalidate cache etc. but nothing is working for me.

Comment: Your compilesdk should be 27 to match the major build tools version of 27.x.x

Comment: Also, your support libraries should have major build version 27.x.x. I mean to say all of the compile “com.android.support” lines in your build.gradle file

Comment: @flopshot that worked, so the trick is to use the latest build version am I right?

Comment: "So I corrected them manually by removing the <<<<<" No, you shouldn't. You should search for `git conflict`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your buildtoolsversion major number 27.x.x is not the same as your compilesdkversion number 26 in your app: build.gradle file.

Each sdk release comes with a buildtools release specifically for that sdk, and they usually aren’t  back ported, so your buildtools 27.x.x has no idea how to build with the sdk 26. Android Studio should have displayed a lint warning highlighting the error.

Comment: Updating compileSdkVersion from 26 to 27 and "com.android.support" to 27.1.1 worked for me,